# Zxing Embedded Barcode Reader using (BarcodeView)

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner, pdf417

My question is when scanning a pdf417 barcode format sometimes it returns a UPC_E format base on the scan result?

here is a snippet of my code

```
 private BarcodeView barcodeView;

    private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
                if (result.getText() != null) {          
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {
            }
        };
```

here is the library

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0'
```

Comment: Anyone knowns if i could set the scanning into just pdf417 format.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem. long time ago :)

```
private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
                if (result.getText() != null) {
                    String barcodeResult = result.getText();
                    String barcodeFormat = result.getBarcodeFormat().toString();
                    if (barcodeFormat.equals("PDF_417")) {
                        try {
                            String barcodeEncodedResult = new ConvertUtil().encodeIntoBase64(barcodeResult);
                            processEncodedResult(barcodeEncodedResult);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to read as PDF_417 barcode format", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the format to scan with intent integrator. Something like :

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this); 
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PDF_147);
intent = integrator.createScanIntent();
barcodeView.initializeFromIntent(intent);
```

Comment: yes but.. i am using it in a custom layout so i need to use  BarcodeView

Comment: by using IntentIntegrator i cannot customize the view it shows a full screen barcode reader